# Run interactive rebase for specific list of commits filtered by author

Tags: git

Lets assume that I need to squash a couple of my commits from feature branch and apply it to master.

Feature branch has this history (master doesn't have this changes):

```
"fix 1"
"fix 2"
...
"fix 22"
...
"fix 78"
...
"fix 100"
```

"Fix 22" & "Fix 78" were added by me, assume others commits added by another persons.

When I use `git rebase -i master` I get all list of commits and I must go through all the list and mark each to drop and (fix 22 & 78) to squash

Do we have a way to get specific to author list of commits in interactive rebase?

Comment: Rebase needs to replay the other commits as well, unless you plan on just deleting what those other authors did? Please explain more about what you hope to accomplish, otherwise it's hard to give advice.

Comment: I think you might need a script to do this.  But I don't think you can eliminate human involvement, because as you replay commits after squashing you can (and likely will) have merge conflicts.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen got it, thank. I think I can resolve it by cherry pick and amend each commit commands.